# Passing an object from one script to another

Tags: powershell

I am having an issue passing an array member to another script. I have a VM build script that pulls from a CSV, I end up with a $VM object with .Name, .CPU, .RAM, .IP, etc. I want to pass that VM object to another script (inside the new server) which can then act on it, but am unable to do so. I have been testing the correct syntax just to pass a simple array, like below, but am still not successful:

CSV:

```
Name,NumCPU,MemoryGB,IPAddress
JLTest01,2,4,172.24.16.25
```

Script1:

```
Function TestMe {
[CmdLetBinding()]
Param (
  [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=1)]
     [array]$arr
)

$arr | Out-GridView
}

TestMe
```

Calling Script:

```
$aVMs = Import-Csv -Path "PathToCsv"

foreach($VM in $aVMs) {  
   $command = "<path>\TestMe.ps1 " + "-arr $($VM)"
   Invoke-Expression $command
}
```

This produces an error, which seems to be on parsing the array. The error states:

> The term 'JLTest01' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At line:1 char:48 + ... \Desktop\TestMe.ps1 -arr @{Name=JLTest01; NumCPU ...

Just trying to figure out what I am doing wrong exactly, and what I need to do to pass the object to the second script.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Invoke-Expression` (which is rarely the right tool and [should generally be avoided for security reasons](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/)):

The stringification of the custom objects output by `Import-Csv` performed by `$($VM)` does not preserve the original objects; it results in a hashtable-*like* representation that isn't suitable for programmatic processing and breaks the syntax of the command line you're passing to `Invoke-Expression`.

Instead, just invoke your script directly:

```
$aVMs = Import-Csv -Path "PathToCsv"

.\TestMe.ps1 -arr $aVMs
```

Note that I'm passing `$aVMs` as a whole to your script, given that your `-arr` parameter is array-typed.

If you'd rather process the objects one by one, stick with the `foreach` approach (but then you should declare the type of your `$arr` parameter as `[pscustomobject]` rather than `[array]`):

```
$aVMs = Import-Csv -Path "PathToCsv"

foreach ($VM in $aVMs) {
  .\TestMe.ps1 -arr $VMs
}
```

Another option is to declare `$arr` as accepting pipeline input, add a `process` block to your script, and then *pipe* `$aVMs` to your script (`$aVMs | .\TestMe.ps1`).

---

Also, don't nest a function of the same name inside your `.ps1` script that you call from within the script, especially not without passing the arguments through; scripts can directly declare parameters, just like functions:

```
[CmdLetBinding()]
Param (
  [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=1)]
  [array]$arr
)

$arr | Out-GridView
```

Comment: I'd dot source the  executive script as `. .\Script1.ps1` and then call  directly the function as `TestMe -arr $aVMs`. Moreover, remove the latter line `TestMe` from `Script1.ps1` script.

Comment: Good point, @JosefZ, I hadn't paid attention to the content of the script; the simplest solution is to not nest a function inside the script and make it accept parameters directly - answer updated.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I appreciate your help. Making the changes you suggested works and passes the object as expected. My only concern is how it will behave if I pass the whole $aVMs array and there are multiple $VM objects within it, but this is a start. If nothing else I can parse the array inside the executive script to ensure I am only targeting the items I need.

Comment: @JLogan3o13, you can stick with the `foreach` approach if you want to, but then you should declare the type of your `$arr` parameter as `[pscustomobject]` rather than `[array]` - please see my update.